# Fallback dosen't work when not using 'menu' attribute

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I want my fallback function to be called when the menu doesn't contains any items. And if I specify the menu name, it works. But not when as I below comment away that attribute. Now nothing happens. No output.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    //'menu'          => 'Menuname', 
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',                    
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'menu-box',
    'items_wrap'      => '<h3>Menuname</h3><ol>%3$s</ol>',
    'walker'          => new NM_Walker_Theme_Menu(),
    'fallback_cb'     => 'theme_fallback',
) );
```

How do I get the `theme_fallback`function to be called, with the wp_nav_menu's attributes, as it does when I specify the `'menu'` name.

Comment: If you uncomment the `menu` parameter and rename it to a menu that doesn't exist - your fallback doesn't work? I think fallback will run if it can't find the menu with name `Menuname`.

Comment: Maybe then, but I want it to fallback if the menu doesn't contain any items. It works when I remove the comment and remove theme_location.